# How to set up the Servlet Path make HTML correctly invoke servlet file?

Tags: html, eclipse, tomcat, servlets

***My goal***: to access a .htm file, and pass the user input to the invoked servlet and display the content.

What i did: I used eclipse Juno to create a dynamic project:ServeletTest. The structure of the project is as followed:

[image]

The servlet file is MyServlet.java   and the related code is:

```
package ylai.Servlet.test;

import java.io.IOException;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
/**
 * Servlet implementation class MyServlet
 */
@WebServlet(description = "test servlet", urlPatterns = { "/MyServlet" })
public class MyServlet extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#HttpServlet()
     */
    public MyServlet() {
        super();
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
     */
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        String info = request.getParameter("info") ;    
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter() ;
        out.println("<html>") ;
        out.println("<head><title>Hello Servlet</title></head>") ;
        out.println("<body>") ;
        out.println("<h1>" + info + "</h1>") ;
        out.println("</body>") ;
        out.println("</html>") ;
        out.close() ;

    }

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
     */
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
           this.doGet(request, response);
    }


}
```

The html file is input.htm .  And the detail code is:

```
<html>
<head><title>This is html file</title></head>
<body>
<form action="myservlet" method="post">
    Type something：<input type="text" name="info">
    <input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

And the web.xml is defined as :

```
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
   version="2.5">

  <display-name>Welcome to Tomcat</display-name>
  <description>
     Welcome to Tomcat
  </description>    
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>myservlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>ylai.Servlet.test.MyServlet</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>myservlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/myservlet</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>  
    </web-app>
```

When i run the input.htm using Built-in Tomcat within the Eclipse, it works fine, and the input content in the input.htm can be displayed by MyServlet.java.  The screen shot is as followed:

[image]

[image]

It seems works fine.

***My Question***:

If i want to modify the value of  in the web.xml as

```
 <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>myservlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/myservletURL</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
```

What i expected was once the input.htm is submitted, it will invoked the serlvet and the web page address should be:

```
http://localhost:8080/ServeletTest/myservletURL
```

But the display page address is still, does not change :

`http://localhost:8080/ServeletTest/myservlet`      with HTTP Status 404 error.

It looks weird!!! The mechanism should be: When i submit the input.htm page, it will  invoke servlet by  servlet-name in the web.xml. In this case, servlet-name is myservlet. Tomcat will use servlet-name to find the actual location of servlet file: MyServlet.java and execute it. The redirect page address would be depends on what you define in . In this case, it should  /ServeletTest/myservletURL
But right now. Servlet file can not be invoked and the page address is not what i expect.

Do i have wrong understand on the servlet invoke mechanism or others?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you changed the **url-pattern** to myservletURL, you will also need to update the form **action** to target this new url.

Comment: Are you sure form action should match with url-pattern? Not Servelt-name in web.xml? I tired, but the problem still here.

Comment: Yes, because the browser will be calling what your web page says to call.  It has no knowledge of what's in the web.xml file, the web.xml tells the server what URL maps to which servlet class.

Comment: Do you mean that the html file will find the redirect page according to action which is the value of <mapping-url> in web.xml, not servlet-name? If so how the html know which servlet it need to submit? the mapping-url is self-define, have no relationship with actual invoke servlet information.

Comment: why do you use webservlet annotation ?

Comment: Your understanding of the servlet invoking mechanism is incorrect.   http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E13222_01/wls/docs81/webapp/web_xml.html#1015060 NOTE: **If the patterns match, the servlet mapped in this element will be called** Your pattern in input.htm does NOT match url-pattern mapping.

Answer (score 1):

```
LifeCycleServlet--@WebServlet("/LifeCycleServlet")
MyServlet--@WebServlet(description = "test servlet", urlPatterns = { "/MyServlet" })
```

delete these lines because here you have mentioned url as MyServlet

or

Change this urlpattern { "/MyServlet" } also

Comment: Lai go to server explorer in eclipse and  by right click select clean tomcat work directory and run once again and let me know this problem.

Comment: if you can send the whole project to me i will test , will give the result. my mail(sun.leo04@gmail.com).Put subject as STACKOVERFLOW.

Comment: I will execute this in my Eclipse and will let you know.PLease delete previous comments in this if you can.

Comment: hai Lai I edited my answer check.I found the problem and corrected.