# How to send a path from a HTML form to a servlet?

Tags: java, servlets, properties-file

I want to send path(it is the path of a properties file) from a HTML form to the servlet. How would the servlet read the path?What should be the code to be written in the servlet?

Comment: What code do you have so far? And what research did you try doing? Are you trying to do something like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13109898/how-to-set-up-the-servlet-path-make-html-correctly-invoke-servlet-file

Comment: If the path to a properties file is on the local machine, the answer is, you can't acces the local machine from the server. if the path is on the website or you somehow upload the file, then it is posible

Answer (score 0):

I think you could solve this by doing something like this:

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
    <body>
      <form action="demo_form.asp">
        First name: <input type="text" name="fname"><br>
        <input type="hidden" name="country" value="Norway">
        <input type="submit" value="Submit">
      </form>
      <p>Notice that the hidden field above is not shown to a user.</p>
    </body>
 </html>
```

**In your servlet**
You then call the doPost method and the *.getParameter("country")*
The example above is from: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_type.asp
I hope this is the solution for your problem